# Where to put custom Vue mixins and helper functions in a Nuxt project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project and I need to make custom functions and Vue mixins to reuse in Vue components and pages.

In which folder should I put the files containing these? Should I create a 'lib' folder at the top level of the Nuxt project and put the files in there?

Extra details if that can help:

- These functions will be imported only when needed (not global)
- These functions will be tested

[Nuxt Directory Structure Documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/directory-structure/)

Comment: Nuxt do not have any specific folder aimed for mixins, you can follow any convention that you'd like here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in my nuxt project, I usually add four folders at the root directory level of the project which is `mixins` for all of my mixins, `models` for the models or classes which I use throughout the app, `services` which contains all my API's endpoints and `utils` which contains all my utility functions and other general functions like my input's validation functions and my directory looks like this:

[image]

in the case of `mixins` you can then import the required mixin into the desired component and use them like you normally would:

```
import someMixin from '@/mixins/someMixin'
...
export default {
  mixins: [someMixin],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can put the mixins file into 2 folders.

1. you can create global-mixin.js into the plugins folder and after that set this file into `plugins: []` part in nuxt.config. [link](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins/#global-mixins)
2. you can create a mixins folder and create mixin.js into that. [link](https://medium.com/@seyijosh44/how-to-use-mixins-in-nuxt-js-826724fa251)

But the nuxt.js's documents suggested that the first solution was correct

Answer (score 2):

As Nuxt has not any specific directory for mixins, you can create them like any other plugin you have in your project. I prefer to have my overly used plugins in a folder named `common`. It is your choice really. But as you want to reuse them throughout your project, then you may want to use global mixins, which are similar, But they can lead to memory leakage when not handled correctly. So we need some kind of flag to prevent it from registering multiple times.

Therefore, create a directory you like (for example `myMixinFolder`). For example I am going to create a mixin file. I create a file inside `myMixinFolder` and name it `my-mixin-plugin.js`.

```js
import Vue from "vue"

if (!Vue.__my_mixin__) {
  Vue.__my_mixin__ = true
  Vue.mixin({ 
    methods: {
      sayIt(name) {
        console.log(`Hello dear ${name}`)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Then add it to `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/my-mixin-plugin.js' },
],
```

Now you can use it in any component like this:

```html
<template>
  <span>{{ sayIt('Batman') }}</span>
</template>
```

Or inside `script`:

```js
this.sayIt('Batman')
```

This way you don't need to import mixins again and again (Although, you need to be careful if you have more than one mixin file to prevent memory leakage).